# How can I display baseline and create text on it?

Tags: minipage, baseline, textwidth

I use the below structure for it:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{minipage}[t]{.9\textwidth}
\leavevmode\rlap
{I want to stop the hrule, at the end of my text.}
\rule{\textwidth}{0.0001pt}
\leavevmode\rlap
{And also I want to stop the hrule, at the end of my text too.}
\rule{\textwidth}{0.0001pt}
\leavevmode\rlap
{And also for here.}
\rule{\textwidth}{0.0001pt}
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

But I want  to be `exactly`   equal   my  `hrule width` and `text width`  together.

My output is:
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a suggestion assuming that there is no linebreak in the text:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\newsavebox\textbox
\newcommand\showbaseline[1]{%
  \leavevmode
  \sbox\textbox{#1}%
  \rlap{\rule{\wd\textbox}{.1pt}}%
  \usebox\textbox
}
\begin{document}
\begin{minipage}[t]{.9\textwidth}
  \raggedright
  \showbaseline{Short text.}\\
  \showbaseline{I want to stop the hrule, at the end of my text.}
  \showbaseline{And also I want to stop the hrule, at the end of my text too.}
  \showbaseline{And also for here.}
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

[image]