# Long underscore in reference item with Biblatex-APA

Tags: biblatex, apa-style, underscore

I need to refer to some case law in my thesis using APA style.

I'm using Biblatex with the following options:

```
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=apa,language=english]{biblatex}
```

I´m mostly following the examples available [here](https://github.com/plk/biblatex-apa/blob/master/bibtex/bib/biblatex-apa-test-references.bib).

However, when a case presents a citation like **576 U.S. ___**, the three underscores don't appear correctly.

My .bib entry is like this:

```
@jurisdiction{Facebook_2021,
keywords    =   {cases},
title       =   {Facebook, Inc. v. Duguid},
citation    =   {592 U.S. \_\_\_},
url         =   {https://www.supremecourt.gov/docket/docketfiles/html/public/19-511.html},
date        =   {2021}
}
```

The problem is that when I compile the file, the citation appears spaces between the underscores, like this: **592 U.S. _ _ _**.

If I leave only the first backlash and remove the others, the final result is only one underscore: **592 U.S. _** , and if I remove all backlashes, so none underscore appears: **592 U.S.**. I also receive lots of errors:

> Missing $ inserted. Test\footfullcite{Facebook_2021}
> Missing { inserted. Test\footfullcite{Facebook_2021}
> Missing { inserted. Test\footfullcite{Facebook_2021}
> Missing } inserted. Test\footfullcite{Facebook_2021}
> Missing } inserted. Test\footfullcite{Facebook_2021}
> Missing $ inserted. Test\footfullcite{Facebook_2021}

Does anyone have any idea on how to fix it?

Thanks!!

Comment: Can you show a minimal example that shows the problem? When I construct one, the underscores are not separated. Maybe this is a font issue? Alternatively you could use something like `\rule{3em}{.5pt}` instead of the underscores which would be font independent.

Comment: Are these underscores meaningful? I've never seen this kind of thing, but I don't know anything about legal citation practice.

Comment: @AlanMunn & everybody else who is wondering about this: https://law.stackexchange.com/q/972

Comment: @moewe Wow. Thanks. I had no idea.

Comment: @AlanMunn, yes, it is part of the reference, so it has to be there.

Comment: @moewe, thanks for the link. I remember reading about it long ago but was not able to provide a good explanation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This appears to be a font issue. With some fonts (e.g. `lmodern`) `\_\_\_` looks like one continuous underscore.

```
\documentclass[american]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=apa]{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@JURISDICTION{11.4:2,
  TITLE         = {Obergefell v. Hodges},
  CITATION      = {576 U.S. \_\_\_},
  URL           = {https://www.supremecourt.gov/opinions/14pdf/14-556_3204.pdf},
  DATE          = {2015}
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
Lorem \autocite{sigfridsson,11.4:2}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: "Obergefell v. Hodges, 576 U.S. ___ (2015)." with continuous underscore]

With other fonts it looks like three underscores with a little but of space between them. In those cases it is probably necessary to fake the desired output with a rule (inspired by [How can I display baseline and create text on it?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/432189/35864)).

```
\documentclass[american]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=apa]{biblatex}

\newsavebox\textbox

\newrobustcmd\tripleunderscore{%
  \leavevmode
  \sbox\textbox{\_\_\_}%
  \rule{\wd\textbox}{.45pt}}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@JURISDICTION{11.4:2,
  TITLE         = {Obergefell v. Hodges},
  CITATION      = {576 U.S. \tripleunderscore},
  URL           = {https://www.supremecourt.gov/opinions/14pdf/14-556_3204.pdf},
  DATE          = {2015}
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
Lorem \autocite{sigfridsson,11.4:2}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: "Obergefell v. Hodges, 576 U.S. ___ (2015)." with continuous underscore]

You can play around with the value `.45pt` to achieve the desired line thickness. You can also directly give the length of the underscore yourself if you are not happy with the length LaTeX calculates, e.g.

```
\newrobustcmd\tripleunderscore{%
  \leavevmode
  \rule{2em}{.45pt}}
```